# android view data from database to list view

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setPerkara(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setTarikhKejadian(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setMasaMula(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setMasaAkhir(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

This is what I am using to call data from `SQLite`. The data is there.But I don't know how to call it and put the data in the list view.

I am using `List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();` in my java program and then I stuck the example I have only show how to see the data in log.

what method should I use to call the data from database and view it in list view?

Comment: You have to use an Adapter to bind you data with a listview. Either a custom Adapter or some Android class like SimpleAdapter. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html

Comment: follow some tutorials, it's not that difficult http://mobilecoder.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/understanding-simplecursoradapter-parameters/ and http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Comment: listTarikh = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listTarikh);
        
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        String[] from = new String[] {DatabaseHandler.KEY_ID,DatabaseHandler.KEY_PH_NO, DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME, DatabaseHandler.KEY_MASAMULA, DatabaseHandler.KEY_MASAAKHIR} ;
        int[] target = new int[] {R.id.listTarikh};
        
        ListAdapter adb = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.senarai, contacts, from, target);
        listTarikh.setAdapter(adb);

it give error at the simple cursor adapter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above you have to use an Adapter I would create your own and add this to you ListView. This is roughly how you would do it, code bit rough as type it straigh into text editor here:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ListAdapter<String> {

 private final List contacts;

//Call to super to set up the adapter
  public ContactListAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Get your View
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    //create the emelements you want to add to list
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(contacts.get(position).getId())

    return rowView
}
}
```

Then add this adapter to your ListView and Initialize it

Hope this helps you

Comment: i have one last question.. how can i add List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts(); into ArrayAdapter<String> = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.lyout, R.id.Id, XXX ); can i just insert it into the XXX?